# Is possible to hide an error in CMD?

Tags: command-line, batch, cmd.exe

Well, i have a batch script to map a folder and execute a .exe file. It is like this

```
net use:p  \\\10.211.0.45\folder$
p:
setup.exe
```

But, when this command runs, this message appears "The password is invalid for \10.211.0.45\folder$. Enter the user name for '10.211.0.45':

I would like to hide only the error "The password is invalid for \10.211.0.45" and show the message Enter the user name for.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can check the error level in a batch command and ask for the input you want.

Comment: Please see:  .....    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812484/batch-file-test-error-level